# Connection to Git through Jenkins with https is throwing an error

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gitlab

I am trying to connect git with Jenkins but facing an issue The error I am getting

Error
**Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git config --local credential.username abcdef" returned status code 129:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unknown option `local'
usage: git config [options]
Config file location
    --global              use global config file
    --system              use system config file
    -f, --file      use given config file**

I am giving the username and password but it is not working.I am using below configuration
Jenkins Version 1.558
Git Plugin : 2.2.12
Git Client Plugin : 1.19.6
Git server Plugin : 1.6

I tried with credentials from the Jenkins server and able to clone the repository

Answer (score 0):

You have outdated git version on the server, and your plugin tries to use the `--local` options, which was added AFAIR around 1.7.
Try to upgrade your git on the jenkins server (which is inside /usr/bin`) to newer version.